# NSString substituting NSData possible, what are consequences?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Suppose I'm storing a stream of ASCII, say `0x0a0b0c00`. What would happen to the data if I store it in an `NSData` instance vs. an `NSString`?  Would the data get converted into something else?  I'm a little confused because they are both buffers holding the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSData is a container to store, as its name suggests, raw binary data. NSData makes **no assumptions** of the format of the binary data. It can be text, images, audio, etc.

NSString **interprets** the data as text with a given encoding: which could be ASCII, Unicode, etc. In most cases, NSString will copy the bytes to its internal data structure to store the raw binary.

If it's not text, use NSData. It's clearer in code to know what's being managed and avoids having to fight string encodings.